# how to change location of OpenSSL config file

Tags: c, openssl

I'm using the openssl downloaded in 
    http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.
The first one of the list.
I installed it in windows x64 system.
When I use openssl to work.
It signed:
    WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
    Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

I'm using windows and it have no /usr/.... instead of C:/...
and the config file is in C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
what can I do？ how to change the config local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the configuration file can be affected by the environment variable [`OPENSSL_CONF`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/config.html).

Since OpenSSL 1.1, initialization via configuration happens automatically. If you need some explicit initialization, you would use [`OPENSSL_init_crypto`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/OPENSSL_init_crypto.html).

Prior to version 1.1, you would use [`OPENSSL_config`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_config.html):

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
void OPENSSL_config(const char *config_name);
```

> **DESCRIPTION**: `OPENSSL_config()` configures OpenSSL using the standard `openssl.cnf` configuration file name using `config_name`.
>
> **NOTES**: The environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` can be set to specify the location of the configuration file.

Comment: OPENSSL_config is depreciated in 1.1.0. Use of OPENSSL_CONF env variable works.

Comment: @lashgar: Thanks, answer updated.